# Cordova 9 build failed "cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;"

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-admob

I have created a cordova project and added android platform. I ran cordova build android the build was successfull, I added plugin cordova-plugin-admob-free then ran ran cordova build android again build failed with the following error

```
platforms\android\app\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AdMob.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
                                    ^
  symbol:   class GoogleApiAvailability
  location: package com.google.android.gms.common
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
D:\test\MyApp2\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\name\ratson\cordova\admob\AdMob.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
        isGpsAvailable = (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(cordova.getActivity()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
```

Version

```
cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

in package.json

```
"cordova-admob-sdk": "0.24.1",
"cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-admob-free": "0.27.0",
"cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the plugin https://admob-plus.github.io/ from the same author and it works without any problem